# Userscripts manipulating aura components

Tags: javascript, aura, aura-attribute

Objective:

To write a userscript that runs on my browser and scrapes data from a specific salesforce dynamic form that I have to fill out during my job.

Summary:

I am using TamperMonkey to run my own custom userscript on my google chrome but in order to scrape data, I need to find where it is stored - I simply can't seem to locate it.

For example, using the dev console we can see that an HTML element during editing will have `"HerearesomewordsIwrote"` written inside the `<textarea>` element which is normal, but when I change what is written to `"NewWordsHere"` the HTML `<textarea>` element doesn't change until i save the form.

Not too surprising considering salesforce uses its own framework which is Aura. But now I don't know where to scrape data from since the resultant HTML code is not reliable.

**Where would a JS script (which would be my userscript on the browser) find the stored attribute of a form field on a salesforce form?? It is impossible to scrape data if you don't know where the data is.**

Help.